# Unable to Access Mysql

Tags: mysql

Trying `Mysql` for first time.  I never set a password but I was unable to access the program.  I tried to reset a password with following method.

> [sudo] password for zphinx:   * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld 
>   [ OK ]  zphinx@zphinx-X550CC ~ $ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
>   & [1] 6301 zphinx@zphinx-X550CC ~ $ 170507 18:08:30 mysqld_safe Can't
>   log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error
>   configuration options for --syslog to take effect. 170507 18:08:30
>   mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'. 170507 18:08:30
>   mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

Sorry that this isn't very specific but I ran into this issue immediately.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is pure admin stuff. DBAs would be in a lot better pisition to help you than sw developers.

Comment: Are you using linux or window?

Comment: Using linux, ubuntu.

Comment: Any update for this question ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1> edit you my.cnf in /etc/mysql dir and add  following line after [mysqld] tag

```
 skip-grant-tables
```

2> then restart you mysql server

```
sudo -i /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

3> now ,you can access mysql without password

```
mysql -u root mysql
mysql> update user set password=password("new_pass") where user="root";
mysql> flush privileges
mysql> quit
```

note that 'new pass' is password you want set.

after reset password,then you have to remove the **skip-grant-tables** in my.cnf which added in setp 1.

Comment: getting this error now `zphinx@zphinx-X550CC ~ $ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                        cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permission denied
                                                                         [fail]
df: '/var/lib/mysql/.': Permission denied
 * /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!`

Comment: type `sudo-i` before performing that action.

Answer (score 0):

> mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists

1. kill all mysqld process

   `killall mysqld mysqld_safe`
2. check whether still there are some mysqld process remained or not

   ```
    ps aux | grep mysqld
   ```
3. If process still exists, run this command

   ```
   killall -9 mysqld mysqld_safe
   ```

Refer from [error mysqld_safe - a mysqld process already exists](https://hoststud.com/resources/resolved-error-mysqld_safe-a-mysqld-process-already-exists.141/)